Estimating capacitance introduced by twisted pair
Imagine that one is routing twisted cables(signal and ground) to a BNC connector from an opamp output; and the twisted cables look like the following:

(source: https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/111299/view/twisted-pair-cable)
To be more specific let's say each twisted cable is a 22 AWG 7 core multicore cable.
If we assume the twisted cable length is 10cm between the opamp output to the BNC connector, is there a way to estimate roughly the capacitance introduced by the twisted pair? Does it depend on twisting frequency and is there a formula to tell roughly what could be the range for such capacitance?

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/twisted-pair-impedance-calculator/

A comment from Gabor_Sz  on the calculator linked by @user1850479 says It looks like this is a simplified formula that doesn’t take into count the twisting density.  The image shows a very tightly twisted pair which should mean a lower effective dielectric constant and a slower velocity of propagation.  Typical twisted pairs in multi-pair cable are much more loosely twisted so that the insulation of the two wires in the pair does not touch the insulation of the next twist.. I'm not sure how to modify the calculation to take into account the twisting density.

@ChesterGillon In fact, those are the parallel-line formulas; twist is ignored completely, as is nonuniformity of the dielectric (i.e. the space around the conductors is partly air).

If tightly twisted you should probably use the original (straight) length and not the shorter (twisted) length in the calculation. Otherwise I doubt the twist density is a major source of error relative to the uncertainty in line spacing and exact dielectric constant. If those matter you should probably measure the precise values.

There are calculators for that, but it simply is same case as two conductors separated by insulating material. You need to know the distance of the wires i.e. thickness of insulation and the dielectric constant of the insulation.
Some formulas take into account the fact that it's a twisted pair wire.
If you just want a rough estimation, CAT5 with 22 AWG has 55pF per meter, so 10cm would be around 5pF anyway.
The only problem left is that it sounds like you need a high frequency transmission line from op-amp to BNC, and your two random wires twisted together has unknown transmission line characteristics, such as impedance.

Not to mention random common mode rejection; the BNC implies unbalanced mode, which may introduce error from the length of twisted pair.

Rule of thumb say pF per inch

@DDuck So that's 4pF instead of 5pF then. Good approximation within 20%.
